# Printing out Twice NASM

Tags: c, assembly, printf, nasm

My question: Why is it printing twice when I'm making one call to printf?
Note that yes, I'm aware I'm allocating space in heap for a variable stored on the stack. I'm only doing this to get used to malloc, pointers, and 'arrays' in NASM.

Compiling in x64 bit machine with:
`nasm -f elf32 -o TEMP.o file.asm`

and:
`gcc -m32 -o exec TEMP.o`

```
extern exit, printf, malloc, free
global main

section .data
format  db  "%s", 10
msg:    db "Hello!!",10
BUF equ $-msg + 1

section .text
main:
    push BUF    ; How many bytes do we want to allocate
    call malloc ; ptr stored in EAX
    add esp, 4  ; clear the last thing on the stack (BUF)
    mov esi, eax    ; new source index at malloc pointer
    xor ecx, ecx    ; clear ECX (counter for us)
loop:
    mov dl, [msg+ecx]   ; mov letter into dl
    mov BYTE [esi+ecx], dl  ; cat dl onto array
    inc ecx         ; add 1 to our ounter
    cmp ecx, BUF-1d
    jl loop

    xor edx, edx
    mov BYTE [esi+ecx], dl
    add esp, 4
    mov esi, eax
    push esi    ;
    push format
    call printf
    add esp, 4*2
    push esi
    call free

    push 0
    call exit
    add esp, 4
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: My appologies. I had written it but had ctr+v'd over it with the NASM code.

Comment: Your strings need to be zero-terminated for `printf`.

Comment: That would be the:     `xor edx, edx` + `mov BYTE [esi+ecx], dl`

Comment: What about your format string?

Comment: It seems that taking out the `push format` was what I needed. I'm simply pushing a string, so I didn't need a format. Thanks!

Comment: Uh, you *DO* need a `format` parameter!  Read Uncontrolled format string - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string

Comment: @Gunner the function [puts](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) might be better suited for playing around in assembly, though note that it appends a newline to the end of the string.

Comment: The OP is using `printf` and needs to learn to use it correctly now while learning, to prevent bugs later.

Comment: @Gunner that's true, not only in assembly..

Comment: The format is indeed redundant since it is just `%s`. But it would have worked if it were null terminated as I had indicated. Without the null termination, the format string becomes `"%s\x10your_string_here"` so the `printf` returns two instances of your string.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to end your strings with `0`

```
format  db  "%s", 10, 0
msg:    db "Hello!!",10 ,0
```

---

Okay i'v read the comments just now and see you said you had code that is meant to insert the `0`s, i'd check that, because i copied/pasted your code and only added the `0`s on the ends of the strings to make it output one string, i didn't even notice the insertion code let alone touch it, but i can only assume that is where your problem is.